# Is there any teritory chart control available on xamarin forms / xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

We are trying to present territory map view with different controls in android and iOS platform using xamarin.forms or Xamarin Native. Is there any map control avaialble to present territory map view in xamarin forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Syncfusion has something similar to what you want in their [Maps](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin/maps)

[image: Screenshot from the controls gallery (courtesy of Syncfusion.com)]

Comment: Thanks @Gerald Versluis, for quick response, Is there anything similar as opensource or free?

Comment: They actually have a community license, but it won't be open source. As far as I know, there isn't a similar one.